# Fitting a grid to data

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I want to fit a grid to data, in the sense that I want to distribute the grid points so that they minimize the distance from each data point to the *closest* grid point. The distance between the gridpoints is not fixed, and there are much fewer grid points than there are data points. Let's consider the one-dimensional case first.

Maybe this is very well-known, but I lack the name of it. If so, please point me towards the solution. Otherwise, I have written the following in Matlab:

```
function S=GridPointSum(Data,x)
% computes sum of minimum distancs to grid point to be minimized. 
M=length(Data);   %number of elements in data.
N=length(x);    %number of elements in grid
%Data=randn(1,M); %data to be fitted with "grid points"
%x is vector with the grid points 
S=0;
for m=1:M
    S=S+min(abs(Data(m)-x));
end
```

and

```
a=randn(1,1000);
    x_0=linspace(-3,3,10);
    %x_0=x_min;

    [x_min,Fval,ExitFlag]=fminsearch(@(x) GridPointSum(a,x),x_0);
```

However, that Matlab code doesn't give the optimal grid. Can you find the error? Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: To see that the grid is not optimal, you can run this script to plot it: figure
hist(a)
hold on
scatter(x_min,zeros(1,10),'r','filled')
scatter(x_0,zeros(1,10),'k','filled')
%s.MarkerEdgeColor = 'r';
hold off

Comment: This optimization problem has many local minima, so the quality of the solution you get depends on the initial conditions. You can try to repeat the optimization with many different (randomly picked) initial conditions, and then select the one which finds the smallest minimum.

Comment: That is a very god idea, thank you!